# Simple If-Then-Else formating SharePoint list (json)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, date-time, json-formatting, column-formatting

The code below I want use to change color of the column Date according to the current date.

But instead it gives me a error. Can somebody give me a hint?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "debugMode": true,
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if([$Date] < @now, '#ff0000', if($Date] = @now; '#008000', if([$Date] > @now; '#0000FF')))"
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax errors in your JSON code. Try using below code:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "style": {
        "color": "=if([$Date] < @now, '#ff0000', if([$Date] == @now, '#008000', if([$Date] > @now, '#0000FF', '')))"
    }
}
```

**Note**:

1. You need to add this JSON code on the field for which you want to change the color.
2. You need to use the **internal name** of your SharePoint column in JSON code (For Date column). You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Reference**:

[Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Also, there will be very rare cases where your date column will be exactly equal to `@now`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this [reference](https://json-schema.org/draft-07/json-schema-release-notes.html) will help, its the recent jJSON Schema updates.

can you try this structure?

```
{
    "type": "integer",
    "minimum": 1,
    "maximum": 1000,
    "if": { "minimum": 100 },
    "then": { "multipleOf": 100 },
    "else": {
        "if": { "minimum": 10 },
        "then": { "multipleOf": 10 }
    }
}
```

let me know if this helps, Happy learning!